# Php pass array to JSON

Tags: php, json, array-push

I have a PHP file that create an array of class with array_push and I need to convert this array to JSON format.
The array is created perfect but when I try to encode to JSON the value returned is an array of empty elements.

the code of php:

```
$return = array();

if($_GET['action'] == 'loadImg'){
    $id = $_GET['idAct'];
    $class = $var->selectActById($id);
    $list = $class->getImatgesAct();
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($list);$i++){
        $class = $var->findimatge($list[$i]->getIdBibl());
        array_push($return, $class);
    }
}
echo json_encode($return,true);
```

The value returned by JSON is:

```
[{},{}]
```

Thanks

EDITED

the var_dump:

```
array
  0 => 
object(imatgeclass)[4]
  private 'idimatge' => string '1' (length=1)
  private 'nomimatge' => string 'hydra' (length=5)
  private 'urlimatge' => string 'biblioimg/2012-05-06-23-19-17.jpg' (length=33)
  1 => 
object(imatgeclass)[3]
  private 'idimatge' => string '2' (length=1)
  private 'nomimatge' => string 'pen' (length=3)
  private 'urlimatge' => string 'biblioimg/2012-05-06-23-19-36.jpg' (length=33)
```

The class definition:

```
class imatgeclass{

private $idimatge, $nomimatge, $urlimatge;

public function setData($idimatge,$nomimatge,$urlimatge){
    $this->idimatge = $idimatge;
    $this->nomimatge = $nomimatge;
    $this->urlimatge = $urlimatge;      
}
public function getIdImatge(){
    return $this->idimatge;
}
public function setIdImatge($idimatge){
    $this->idimatge = $idimatge;
}
public function getNomImatge(){
    return $this->nomimatge;
}
public function setNomImatge($nomimatge){
    $this->nomimatge = $nomimatge;
}
public function geturlimatge(){
    return $this->urlimatge;
}
public function setUrlImatge($urlimatge){
    $this->urlimatge = $urlimatge;
}
}
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($return);` output?

Comment: is the value of $class an object?  If so make sure the properties of the object are public - json_encode does not access private properties. EDIT - to clarify - json_encode can access private properties but only if run from a method within the class.

Comment: What does `$var->findimatge($list[$i]->getIdBibl())` output? It is overwriting the previous value of `$class`

Comment: yes, it's for create the array. I modified the code tring to found the solution.

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. `var_dump($return);` shows all the array created, and all the values that is shown are correct.

Comment: @TheOx all the method and properties of the class `$class` ara public. And yes the `$class`is an object.

Comment: Have you tried calling `json_last_error()` to see if it returns an error?

Comment: is there any properties of this `$class` object? Please show the definition of `$class

Comment: @Fran - can you post the var_dump output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your object properties are all private - they need to be public in order to be accessible to json_encode.  Or you need to call json_encode from within an object method.

Comment: @TheOnyx Thank you very much, I made a mistake with the private, thank you now it works.